# converting tuples to lists in list

Tags: python, list, tuples

I am attempting to convert tuples in lists of a list to lists. More accurately, I just would like to remove the tuples in lists. The original dataset looks like

```
collections = [[None], [(u'John Demsey ', u' Cornelia Guest')], [(u'Andres White ', u' Margherita Missoni')], [(u'Bibi Monahan, Tuki Br', u'o, ')], [(u'W$
```

What I would like to achivee is:

```
collections = [[None], [u'John Demsey ', u' Cornelia Guest'], [u'Andres White ', u' Margherita Missoni']...]
```

Nevertheless, with the following code, I fail to achieve my goal.

```
def conv():
    for i in range(len(collections)):
        if collections[i] != None:
            collections[i] = list(collections[i])
        else:
            collections[i][0] = list(collections[i][0])
    return collections[i]

conv = conv()
print(conv)
```

In the code, I attempted to convert tuples to lists. However, this does not look work. Could someone help me identify the problem and help me correct this? Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather go for `chain` in `itertools` and list comprehension:

```
from itertools import chain

[list(i) if i else [i] for i in chain.from_iterable(collections)]

#Out[110]:
#[[None],
# [u'John Demsey ', u' Cornelia Guest'],
# [u'Andres White ', u' Margherita Missoni']]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help :)

Answer (score 2):

Try to do it this way:

```
def conv():
    return [list(c[0]) if isinstance(c[0], tuple) else c for c in collections]
```

In your code you also return just the last element of list.